# the_title() Returns the page title instead of the post

Tags: loop, title

I'm using a custom page for listing my posts, now using the loop and the_title() returns the page title instead of the posts.

My loop is a simple:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <p class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

and what i mean with a custom page is:

[image]

instead of using the `index.php` to show the posts im using `blog.php`.

Comment: How does your loop look like?

Comment: @birgire included it in the question

Comment: You mention a custom page for listing posts, is this an archive-template or are you using [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or a secondary query ( [`WP-Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) )?

Comment: it's not clear how you fetch the extra posts, but the loop you posted is normal/expected when you display the current page info in your page template. Note that this is fetching the data from the main global `$wp_query`.

Comment: @birgire I'm not such an expert in WP stuff. Can you provide an explanation or show me the right way to do it.

Comment: @AliAlmoullim If you're trying to create a Blog Page, you can assign that under `Settings -> Reading -> Static Posts Page`.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee thats redirect me to `index.php`, or shows `index.php` not `blog.php`

Comment: Rename `blog.php` to `home.php`. Refer to the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to learn how templates are selected.

Comment: worked @Milo@Howday_McGee